# How to loop the JavaScript iterator that comes from generator?

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator, ecmascript-6

Let's assume that we have following generator:

```
var gen = function* () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    yield i;
  }
};
```

What is the most efficient way to loop through the iterator ?
Currently I do it with checking manually if `done` property is set to `true` or not:

```
var item
  , iterator = gen();

while (item = iterator.next(), !item.done) {
  console.log( item.value );
}
```

Comment: next is a function which return an object `iterator.next().value` `iterator.next().done` ..so it should be `item().value` and `item().done`

Comment: If your browser supports [for... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), feel free to go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way to iterate any iterable (an object which supports @@iterator), is to use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), like this

```
'use strict';

function * gen() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
}

for (let value of gen()) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Or, if you want an Array out of it, then you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), like this

```
console.log(Array.from(gen());
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: @thefourtheye, `const value of gen()` triggers an error in Firefox 42 (*SyntaxError: invalid for/in left-hand side*). `let value of gen()` works.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Can you please try that in strict mode?

Comment: Yup, I did ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1yjvpro/)). May be a Firefox issue, though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The language for your Fiddle is set to Javascript 1.7 :)

Comment: @RGraham, that's necessary for `let` to be recognized. In "plain" JavaScript mode, neither `const value of`, nor `let value of` work (but `var value of` does).

Comment: But JS1.7 isn't an ES6 implementation is it? "plain" Javascript would trigger native implementation of FF42 which should have full support for ECMAScript `const` and `for..of`. Or perhaps I'm confused about the JS1.7 implementation

Comment: Unfortunately the `for..of` does not work with generators in Typescript by default.  :-(  You gotta just use next/done.  or else use Array.from

Answer (score 7):

A self-contained, single-line alternative to the `while` loop in the question is the `for` loop. And for the special case of iterating through for pure side effect or depletion, rather than doing something with the results at the end, we avert the issue of binding the next item value, then not using it in a `for-of` solution:

```js
for (let n = iterator.next(); !n.done; n = iterator.next()) {}
```