# hasNext() for ES6 Generator

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-6, generator

How would I implement hasNext() method for a generator. I have tried many options like adding the generator as a return statement and yielding from the closure. Getting the first value printing it and then using the while etc, but none of them actually worked.

I know I can use for of or while like [How to loop the JavaScript iterator that comes from generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333852/how-to-loop-the-javascript-iterator-that-comes-from-generator)  but still wondering if I can add hasNext().

```
function *range(start,end){

    while(start < end){
        yield start; 
        start++
    }
}

let iterator = range(1,10); 

// so I can do something like this. 
while(iterator.hasNext()){
   console.log(iterator.next().value); 
}
```

Comment: The cited question clearly states that `done` should be used in this case. `hasNext` defies the purpose of the generator, it is iterated lazily, it is not known if it is the last iteration until the next `next()`.

Comment: I get that and I am just trying to reason about this. Not sure what you mean by "hasNext defies the purpose of the generator".

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi: You cannot look ahead without consuming the value. In other words, in order to know whether there *is* a next value, you have to get the next value. So if the caller called `hasNext` and result is `true`, the caller would *not* be able to get that next value.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you. I guess my question is wether I can have an outer function that returns an object that is a generator and also hasNext and when the while is not true it sets the hasNext to false.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi please check my answer bellow. There is npm package you can use for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple non-`for…of` way to loop an iterator is

```
for (let iterator = range(1, 10), r; !(r = iterator.next()).done; ) {
    console.log(r.value);
}
```

If you really want to use `hasNext`, you can do that as well, but it's a bit weird:

```
const iterator = range(1, 10);
iterator.hasNext = function hasNext() {
    const r = this.next();
    this.current = r.value;
    return !r.done;
};
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    console.log(iterator.current);
}
```

Comment: _const r = this.next();_ - obtaining value is not required if I know the underlying structure, for example, if I'm iterating an array I can check if `arr[nextIndex]` is not undefined and if I'm not using `generator` functions. But as I understand it's required for built-in objects like `map` etc. Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: @Maximus Generators (and Iterators in general) do not expose any underlying structure - that's what this question was about. Of course, when iterating an array manually your "hasNext" is just the usual `index < arr.length`, yes.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I've modified my comment a bit. Take a look please. And what are `this.current` and `this.done`?

Comment: Thanks for alerting me about `this.done`, it should have been `r.done` indeed

Comment: Aha, it makes sense now. I was thinking maybe it's some internal representation of iterators returned by generators. Btw, do you also maybe know if `for..of` loop checks specifically for `done:true`? By running experiments it seems to be so but I can't find any mentioning of this in docs.

Comment: Yes, [that's exactly what happens](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-iteratorcomplete)

Comment: I am missing something or the method "hasNext" is **not** idempotent i.e. every call mutates state of the iterator?

Comment: @svobol13 Yes, in the implementation above `hasNext()` advances the iterator and `.current` accesses the element. If you want to keep using `next()` for advancing and have `hasNext()` "peek" for at most one element, it becomes a lot more complicated.

Comment: @svobol13 Something like `iterator => ({ done: undefined, value: undefined, hasNext() { if (this.done === undefined) { Object.assign(this, iterator.next(); } return this.done; }, next() { if (this.done !== undefined) { this.done = undefined; return this.value; } else { return iterator.next().value; }})` could do it

Answer (score 0):

You can create and return an object from `range` having `hasNext` defined as `Boolean` by checking if `start + 1 < end`; recursively call a function, `hasNext`  if generator `.next().done` is `false` and `hasNext` property of object at `generator.next().value` is set to `true`, else perform other task

```js
function* range(start, end) { 
  let next = () => start + 1 < end;
  let g = {
    hasNext: next(),
    currentValue: start
  };
  while (start < end) {
    yield g;
    g.currentValue = ++start;
    g.hasNext = next();
  }
}

let iterator = range(1, 10);

function hasNext(gen) {
  let curr = gen.next();
  if (!curr.done) {
    if (curr.value.hasNext) {
      console.log(`hasNext:${curr.value.hasNext}`
                 , `currentValue:${curr.value.currentValue}`);
      hasNext(gen);
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(curr.value, null, 2));
    }
  }
}

hasNext(iterator);
```

Comment: This calls `iterator.next()` twice in each loop. Once for the `console.log`, once for the `while` check.

Comment: @cdbajorin Is expected result not returned?

Comment: No, it ends up logging every other. You need to bind `iterator.next()` to a variable, and use that variable's `value` and `done`.

Answer (score 0):

I created this simple module. It allows you to decorate any iterator and obtain information whether there is more elements.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/iterable-has-next

Usage is as simple as that:

```
//...
const { extendIterator } = require('iterable-has-next')
const extendedIterator = await extendIterator(yourIterator)
while (extendedIterator.hasNext()) {
    const { value } = await extendedIterator.next()
    console.log(value)
}
//...
```

You can try it out 
https://repl.it/repls/YummyWrathfulRhombus

Comment: @Bergi please check links in the post. There is repl.it which illustrates "how you can use it" and in the npm package/repository you can see how it works internally.

i.e. you can use it for iteration like `while (it.hasNext()) { console.log((await it.next()).value) }`. Anyhow iteration isn't the main reason for this reason. I believe the most valuable use case is to get answer to question "is this element last?".

Comment: Those are important things and [should be answered in the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/183280), not in some linked page.

Comment: @Bergi please check updated answer and let me know if it better understandable for you. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Wait, why does it return a promise now that one needs to `await`?

Comment: @Bergi In that way it is compatible with async iteration while it does make no harm to sync iteration.

Comment: Uh, having to `await` something means making your function asynchronous, which definitely harms synchronous iteration.

Comment: Yep, there is always price to be paid when compromise is done. But thanks for input I might introduce both sync and async iteration APIs if real-world need exists for that.

I do not think iterating over sync iterator in async way makes harm. Might be just not intuitive but not harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative. Instead of using a generator function, create a regular function and have it return an object with custom implementations for `hasNext()` and `next()` and add a user-defined iterable for `for...of` loops:

```js
function getRange(start, end) {
    return {
        hasNext() {
            return start <= end;
        },
        next() {
            return start <= end ? start++ : undefined;
        },
        *[Symbol.iterator]() {
            while(start <= end) yield start++;
        }
    };
}

console.log('Test iteration A');
let iteratorA = getRange(1, 10);

while(iteratorA.hasNext()) {
    console.log(iteratorA.next());
}


console.log('\n\nTest iteration B');
let iteratorB = getRange(20, 30);

for(let index of iteratorB) {
    console.log(index);
}
```